# Detect face shape (oval, square, diamond)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there any algorithm to detect the face shape (oval, square, diamond, ....) giving the detected face of an image captured by a normal webcam?

[image]

Comment: KLT algorithm in Opencv

Comment: I don't know exactly how would KLT help in this problem!

Comment: I dont think it's an easy task... You can detecr many faces with haarcascade classifiers pretrained in openCV, but I guess it will be hard to detect the contours in the way you'll need them, because of perspective effects and so on...

Comment: @AhmedHegazy  Did you get any solution ?

Comment: @Mrug No, I dropped it, I was just researching.

Comment: @AhmedHegazy Transfer Learning using VGG/ Inception V3 or Resnet for image classification can definitely solve this if correct training data set is provided

Comment: yes, you can find the shape of face in image, using dlib's model for shape predictor and using mathematics finding length of forehead, chickbone, jawline, angle of jawline. I have implemented this to get face shape, do check this repository for face shape. let me know if you have any doubt https://github.com/Nitish1206/face_shape_without_model

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to see how detect simple shape, for example see  [detecting simple shapes in an image tutorial](https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/detecting-simple-shapes-in-an-image/). Another point to start can be [face recognition](http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html).

Comment: I know about finding contours but I don't think that would help in this problem because the shapes could result in similar outputs like the oblong and square one.

Comment: Have API fees, can get shape face?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the statistical model of head by using Active [Appearance Model](https://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/) (AAM). You can start from here. Also there is an Opencv function [POSIT](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Posit) to estimate the Pose of an 3D Object using OpenGL. You can also have a look at it. Hope this helps!